# select query + join tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called indx_0 where I select all "pid" (product id) cominations with "wid" (word id) grouping them by products that match the most words. Now, since the actual words are stored within a different table called "windex" the table indx_0 only contains product ID matched with the ID of the word.

Here is the current query I use to get the results.

```
SELECT pid, count(*) WordMatchCount
   FROM indx_0 
   WHERE wid in ( 294, 20591, 330 )
   group by pid
   order by WordMatchCount desc
   limit 1000
```

Say I search for "ddr memory card" I will NOT get the result that contains "ddr3"  prioritized over any other keyword since it searches for exact match. so "ddr memory card" and "phone memory card" would be treated as equal since neither "ddr3" nor "phone" equals to ddr.

I want to use join and LIKE (or any other preferable way) to allow "ddr" match against "ddr3" or "ddr2" very closely to prioritize it over other results where there is no close match.

Here are table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `windex` (
  `word` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `wid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  PRIMARY KEY (`wid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `word` (`word`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=834922 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `indx_0` (
  `wid` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `pid` int(7) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `wid` (`wid`,`pid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Is this possible?

thank you!

Comment: please menthion table structure properly

Comment: is there no primary key in `indx_o` also tell me which is parent table and which is child table..means in terms of `foreign key`.

Comment: your query doesn't include anything from `windex`

Comment: windex is parent and indx_0 is child - or so i think its supposed to be. I havent assigned foreign key yet but ill have to work on that. i realize the query doesnt include anything from windex but i want to create one that does. thanks for all your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're filtering by word id, you're obviously not getting close matches. Every ID has a specific word. What you want is to query the IDs directly from `windex` and looking for the matches in `indx_0`.

```
SELECT i0.pid, count(*) WordMatchCount
FROM indx_0 AS i0
LEFT JOIN windex AS wi ON (wi.wid = i0.wid)
WHERE wi.word REGEXP '(.*)ddr(.*)|(.*)memory(.*)|(.*)card(.*)'
group by i0.pid
order by WordMatchCount desc
```

I'd make sure to run `EXPLAIN` and index the appropriate columns, though.